# Is it possible to have a Faceted Navigation/Filters on a Product Tag page?

Tags: tags, navigation

I am planning the site structure, for a future WordPress powered eCommerce website.

I am wondering if it is possible to place a suitable Faceted Navigation and/or filters on a Product Tag page?  I have not, knowingly, come across any sites who have implemented this.  Just wondering if this is possible, without causing any problems?

As a secondary question, does anyone see any potential problems from placing 'Product Category specific' Faceted Navigation/Filters or should such features be kept the same throughout all product Categories, even if certain values are not applicable to certain Product Categories?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest evaluating the premium plugin FacetWP (I am not affiliated with them), that supports faceted navigation and filters for WooCommerce too. https://facetwp.com/using-facetwp-with-woocommerce/

Or any other similar plugin of course, I know only FacetWP myself.

As for the second question, I think that such plugins manage the display of specific filters automatically, excluding non-pertinent ones.